# Can I jump to next cell containing invalid data in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google sheet containing lots of data, and some of it doesn't respect the data validation rules (and the little red triangle appears). Since I have a lot of data, it's quite a long process to find all occurrences of invalid data. I assumed there would be a "jump to next invalid data" feature or something, but I can't find it. Am I missing anything?

Comment: It depends on what kind of data validation rule you have setup - can you elaborate first on what the rule/condition is that deems it invalid and causes the triangle?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [filter](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?hl=en) view to show only rows containing an error.

On the column you want to check, create a filter, set filter option to "*Filter by Condition*" > "*Custom formula is...*" > "`=iserror(indirect("r"&row()&"c"&column(),FALSE))`"

where `indirect("r"&row()&"c"&column(),FALSE)` is just a fancy way of saying "this cell" (sorry, no easier way), and 
`iserror()` check if the value is invalid.

Here is an [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tEeyHBBHzElODJfPaPyPdIRqYOALeiN9wRj3S3W6wnU/)

Comment: No, this question is not about _errors_ but about _data validation_: `iserror()` checks if the value of the cell has an error, i.e. cannot be displayed, and not if it doesn't respect data validation rules, which are user-defined (e.g. value should be one of several fixed possibilities).

Comment: There is an easier way of saying "this cell": just directly refer to the first cell to which the formula applies, in a way that the formula could be "expanded" to the following cells. So in your example spreadsheet (where the filter is on column C, with data starting at C2), you can filter by the formula `=iserror(C2)`.

Answer (score 0):

"A:A" range contains data validation from "Sheet2!A2:A6"

Global Filter >> Column A >> Custom Formula

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6,A2)<1
```

This will filter all data which doesn't match the "sheet2!A2:A6" range.

Answer (score -1):

on another column, set up a countif formula for each row based on the data validation values

all invalid values will return a value of 0.

then, filter this column based on value 0.

Tada!